# iPhone - is this screen available and customisable or do I need to create it from scratch?

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, custom-fields

I have noticed that in some apps they use what appears to be the the native display screen for a contact, it shows the contact photo, name, phone numbers and options to text message and add to favourites.

But it also will have some customized fields in it also like missed calls or some other non native contact information,

Here is an example screen shot taken from the Viber application:

[image: Viber screenshot]

I am quite new to iPhone development and I was wondering if this screen is made available to developers so that a contacts information can be presented from within an application with custom fields or if it is not and has to be developed from scratch?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the help, with it I have successfully recreated the screen in a static manner, I have one more question and that is how would I make the cell that has the outgoing calls in it react to dymanic data?

So for instance there could be 10 calls there, so how do I adjust the size of the cell on the fly? And also whats the best object to use to allow the calls to be displayed? At the moment I'm using a UITextView to display the static data but I dont think this will work for dynamic data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the developer made this screen there self, it just an UITableView with some custom UITableViewcells.

You can use the UITableView haderView property to insert the the top view with the image.
The just add sections for all the white cells, make use the the tableview style is set to grouped.

Comment: Would the outgoing calls section also be part of the header?

Comment: Could be, or to make it easier I would use tablecells for them to.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot is probably showing a custom UI that is made to look similar to the standard one.

You can get a similar interface with some limited customization options with the `ABPersonViewController` class (in the AddressBookUI framework). It basically takes an address book entry (`ABPerson`, you can also create this from scratch) and allows you to specify which properties (phone numbers, email addresses...) to show.

You can also customize what happens when you tap on a property by implementing the `personViewController:shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:property:identifier:` method in the view controller's `delegate`.

Answer (score 1):

The above screen can be created by using `UITableView`. Since u're new to iPhone..I would suggest you to first go through some basics.

For `UITableView`, Here's the Link..

[UITableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Also look for `UITableView` Cell Formatting in google.

Hope dat helps... :)
happy coding